# Zero magnetic quantum number in Classical physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, atomic-physics

I was reading a book on Atomic Physics where it was stated that

> "In space quantisation of an electron the state with magnetic quantum
>   number $(m)=0$ was always excluded on the ground that application of
>   electric field would case the electron to collide with the nucleus.
>   But later we will see that in quantum mechanics, the states $m=0$ are
>   allowed."

So can somebody explain a bit more extensively why classical mechanics forbids the state with $m=0$ but quantum mechanics doesn't?

Comment: Can you provide a reference to the book?

Comment: @J.Murray Introduction to Atomic Spectra, H.E White. And the given statement is from chapter 2, Sommerfeld's elliptic orbits and space quantisation

Comment: For those of us not overly familiar with the early attempts at quantum theory, the relevant text can be found [here](https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToAtomicSpectra/page/n63) at the top of p.51, though the context on the preceding few pages is important.

Answer (score 1):

> Zero magnetic quantum number in Classical physics

There are no quantum numbers in classical physics, so there is a contradiction in the title.

[$m$ is a quantum number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_quantum_number#As_a_component_of_angular_momentum) dependent on $l$, it is a projection of the angular momentum  on the z axis.

$L_z$, the magnitude of the angular momentum in the z direction, is given by

$L_z=m.ℏ$

Exploring quantized states with the Bohr  and semi-classical models,  before the *theory* of quantum mechanics developed, orbits were a planetary model, one would  exclude the $l=0$ quantum states , because they would pass through the nucleus. The orbit would be a straight line through it because of zero angular momentum. In the planetary model this meant the electron would annihilate on the proton , and there would be  no atoms.

Edit after given link by J.Murray:

For higher $l$ values , example $l=1$the three projections m=1, m=0, and m=-1 would add orbits, differentiating them and allowing a better description  of the observed atomic spectra.

The argument in [the text](https://archive.org/details/IntroductionToAtomicSpectra/page/n63) for excluding $m=0$ for all $l$, is that such a state in an atom would change with the application of an electric field , so even though the angular momentum would be $1$ (in $ℏ$ units), the electron orbit would pass through the nucleus and annihilate. ( I have not checked the claim, that an electric field would force the orbit through the nucleus for $m=0$ for all $l$, I expect it is correct as an electric  or magnetic field would induce a rotation to a classical orbt). As atoms are stable this situation had to be excluded.

The development of the wave equations of quantum mechanics and the [Born rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Born_rule) (postulate)  which directly connected measurements with probabilities, give [orbitals](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Chemical/eleorb.html) and not orbits for  the electrons in an atom, i.e. probability distributions. So there exists a *probability* for an electron to exist in the nucleus, but it is very small. The dimensions of the nucleus are orders of magnitude smaller than the orbital space:  fermi (~$10^{-15}$ meters) for the  size of nucleus, microns (~$10^{-6}$ meters) for orbitals.

[Electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture) in the nucleus shows that in certain nuclei the probability is measurable.

Comment: I've posted a link to the relevant text as a comment to the question.  The question is in the context of Sommerfeld's semi-classical quantization procedure for elliptical orbits (a subject which I know almost exactly nothing about).